# Configure OSX Clang to be case sensitive to include statements

Tags: c++, macos, clang

I know that case sensitivity in C++ include statements is a file system issue (related questions [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCAQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F1951951%2Fwhen-including-header-files-is-the-path-case-sensitive&ei=L8UuVOfZNs3IsASG9IGQDw&usg=AFQjCNGC5ZXrSApvs7G8ctY6e5fGSvOjGg&sig2=T1Vqzu-tsp9Thg1hwviKpg&bvm=bv.76802529,d.cWc) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1951951/when-including-header-files-is-the-path-case-sensitive)).

Is it possible to configure Clang to require case sensitive matches to prevent cross platform build issues?

Comment: If the code works in a case-*sensitive* environment it should also work in a case-*insensitive* environment. Configuring Clang to be case-sensitive doesn't seem like much of a cross-platform issue in such a case, except for possibly catching build errors in a case-sensitive environment sooner.

Comment: @user2864740: The issue is for those poor souls working in an insensitive environment, who might like to avoid portability issues. Sadly, not everyone can choose their development environment.

Comment: @MikeSeymour Right, but unless someone accidentally uses the wrong casing (modern case-insensitive file-systems still store case information, so the reason would be PEBKAC) then there is no issue. And using the wrong casing on an import is arguably no different than writing other invalid/UB code - it is a code mistake.

Comment: @user2864740: Indeed, it's a mistake. But a lot of time can be saved when mistakes are diagnosed automatically - as this one can be (at least in principle). Hence the question: can this compiler be configured to diagnose it?

Comment: Support for this (in form of a warning, anyway) is here as of June 2016: http://llvm.org/viewvc/llvm-project?view=revision&revision=272584

Answer (score 3):

Clang now has these warning flags:

```
-Wnonportable-include-path
-Wnonportable-system-include-path
```

The first is for quoted includes and the second is for angle bracket includes. They can even be mapped to errors:

```
-Werror=nonportable-include-path
-Werror=nonportable-system-include-path
```

Presumably, they're not enabled by default because they can slow down the compile. I haven't taken the time to investigate just how much.

Comment: Is there a way to turn these on from Xcode UI? and if not - where in the target build-settings do I apply custom flags to CLANG ?

Comment: In build settings for the project there's an option called `Other Warning Flags`.

Answer (score 1):

Well, as you stated, and as those questions stated, it's a file system issue. If you formatted your OS X drive as case-sensitive, then it might work, but really you should probably find a different way of differentiating headers.

Comment: As Mike commented, the idea is to diagnose a mistake at compile time. The use case is a header that has capitalization for readability, not differentiation.

Comment: Reformatting seems like a "nuclear option." In theory, it seems like it would be possible to make the compiler more restrictive than the filesystem, but perhaps it is naive to think so.

Comment: But as user2864740 states, this is not any different from any other code mistake. The problem, as I said, is because the (insensitive) filesystem will treat source.cpp and sOuRcE.cpp as IDENTICAL whenever it is queried for the file. They refer to the SAME FILE, and two files could not even exist with those different capitalizations in the same folder on a case-insensitive system. If the computer can't even handle the difference at a filesystem level, how could the compiler?

Comment: As to the 'The use case is a header that has capitalization for readability, not differentiation.' thing, I understand what you mean, but the problem you are trying to solve is *differentiating* between different capitalizations of the same header name, correct? That is what I was referring to - your problem, not the use case.

Comment: Yes, I see what you mean by differentiate. It sounds like the answer to my question is "No. The compiler is limited by the filesystem and cannot be made more restrictive." Is that right?

Comment: 'Cannot' is a strong word. It would probably be possible in some way, but I am fairly certain that the cost of bandaging the problem (programming something, reformatting, etc.) would outweigh the cost of simply not causing the problem (enforcing case-insensitive naming rules). I searched around a bit and couldn't find anything that suggests you can work around the issue, so a fix would likely be fairly error-prone and complicated. But as with almost everything in programming, 'anything is (theoretically) possible' - so I am reluctant to say 'cannot' in an absolute sense.

Comment: not true - In my case, I have my own class "MobileNet.h" + .m that collides with an xcode auto generated "mobilenet.h" + .m that are generated from a .mlmodel file in the derived-data folder - but my code erroneously finds the generated files instead of my own files - despite me using the correct case - #import "MobileNet.h"