# Error in including file - Inheritance

Tags: c++

I have an issue on including the header file to my cpp.
This is on inheritance issue.

In my main, I tried to include package,
however, it doesn't seems to be able to include.
Error was `cannot open source file package.h`

**Package.h**

```
#ifndef package_inc_h
#define package_inc_h
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Package {
    string name;
    string address;
    string country;
    int zipCode;
    double weight;
    double costPerKg;

public:
    Package();
    Package(string name,string address,string country, int zipCode,double weight, double costPerKg);

    string getName();
    void setName(string name);

    string getAddress();
    void setAddress(string address);

    string getCountry();
    void setCountry(string country);

    int getZipCode();
    void setZipCode(int zipCode);

    double getWeight();
    void setWeight(double weight);

    double getCostPerKg();
    void setCostPerKg(double costPerKg);

    double calculateCost(double weight, double cost);


};
#endif
```

**Package.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Package.h"

using namespace std;

Package::Package() {

};

Package::Package(string name, string address, string country, int zipCode, double weight, double costPerKg) {
    this->name = name;
    this->address = address;
    this->country = country;
    this->zipCode = zipCode;
    this->weight = weight;
    this->costPerKg = costPerKg;
};

string Package::getName() {
    return name;
};


void Package::setName(string name) {
    this->name = name;
};

string Package::getAddress() {
    return address;
};

void Package::setAddress(string address) {
    this->address = address;
};

string Package::getCountry() {
    return country;
};

void Package::setCountry(string country) {
    this->country = country;
};

int Package::getZipCode() {
    return zipCode;
};

void Package::setZipCode(int zipCode) {
    this->zipCode = zipCode;
};


double Package::getWeight() {
    return weight;
};

void Package::setWeight(double weight) {
    this->weight = weight;
    if (weight < 0) {
        cout << "Weight cannot be negative" << endl;
    }


};

double Package::getCostPerKg() {
    return costPerKg;
};


void Package::setCostPerKg(double costPerKg) {
    this->costPerKg = costPerKg;
    if (costPerKg < 0) {
        cout << "costPerKg cannot be negative" << endl;
    }

};

double Package::calculateCost(double weight,double cost) {
    double totalCost;
    totalCost = weight * cost;
    return totalCost;
};
```

**main**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Package.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {



}
```

Comment: Are you sure the file name is correct?  Is `package.h` in a location where the compiler will look for include files?

Comment: its case sensitive, its a difference between `#include"package.h"` and `#include"Package.h"`. In your error its written with a small 'p'

Comment: @Jonas that depends on the filesystem [When including header files, is the path case sensitive?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1951951/when-including-header-files-is-the-path-case-sensitive) (on Windows, it is not case sensitive).

Comment: IMO You should add exact compiler statement ad exact compiler error message.
Most probably you haven't told your compiler where to look for your include files.

Comment: @crashmstr i did not know that, so ignore my first comment iff you are using windows