# Is including c++ libraries case insensitive?

Tags: c++, uppercase, case-insensitive

```
#include <IOSTREAM>

int main() {
  std::cout << "hi\n";
  return 0;
}
```

I tried to do it IOSTREAM instead of iostream and it runs with no errors, but how the library names are case insensitive?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When including header files, is the path case sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1951951/when-including-header-files-is-the-path-case-sensitive)

Comment: On some operating systems file systems can be case sensitive.

Comment: Linux is case sensitive for file names, Windows is not!