# CMake adding case insensitive source files

Tags: c++, linux, cmake

I'm trying to build binaries natively in linux for an existing project with CMakeLists.txt's already built. I keep running into issues where the CMakeLists.txt is trying to add a header or source file but cannot. The source file exists in the directory its looking in but the cases dont match. For example, here is one of the header searches:

```
set(Headers
    resource.h
    stdafx.h
    ...
)
```

I had gotten an error saying `fatal error: stdafx.h: No such file or directory`, yet the file that was in the directory was `StdAfx.h` instead of `stdafx.h`. Apparently CMake cannot make the connection that these are the same files.

My issue is, this project file is 6 gb worth of code, and if I have to go in and change the includes for every single mis-capitalized file, I'm never gonna finish anything. Is there a way for me to tell CMake that the file names might have different capitalization? Or am I stuck doing everything by hand until it works.

EDIT:
It looks as though its the Linux file system that is case sensitive, so I'm removing the cmake tag, as it is not an issue with cmake. Im looking for a solution that would allow me to change all the `#include <....>` lines within the .cpp files to match the existing header filenames instead of changing the .h file names.

EDIT: Just for anyone coming to this later, the full error is this:

```
[ 1%] Building CXX object Source/UeiSimuDriver/CMakeFiles/UeiSimuDriver_vc15.dir/StdAfx.cpp.o
In file included from /var/tmp/<workspaceHash>/Framework/Source/UeiSimuDriver/StdAfx.cpp:2 
fatal error: stdafx.h: No such file or directory
#include "stdafx.h"
compilation terminated
```

Comment: How many such files are there? Can you just check for existence of the lower-case version, then add the upper-case version instead if the lower-case does not exist?

Comment: Are you sure that it is cmake that gives the error? And not for example the compiler, or the underlying buildsystem (make, ninja)?

Comment: It sounds like someone added case-insensitive filenames to `CMakeLists.txt` based on Windows development. It also sounds like you need to go through `CMakeLists.txt` and fix them manually now that you are supporting Unix and Linux.

Comment: @eerorika It may not be a cmake issue, seems to me that c++ in linux is case sensitive when it comes to include files, unlike windows.

Comment: @squareskittles, there are about 100 ish .cpp files and maybe 50 or so .h files.

Comment: What do you expect to happen if CMake looks for `abc.h` but there are `Abc.h` and `aBc.h` in one folder. Which file should be choosen? If this situation is not possible use a script to change the case for all files in your project to lower case.

Comment: @Thomas Sablik The project was built in windows, and for some reason the creators of the project didnt stick to a naming convention. There arent any ocurrences of the `Abc.h` vs `aBc.h`, as there will only be one.

Comment: Then there will be no conflicts if you use a script to change all filenames to lower case

Comment: `grep -E '\.h|\.c|\.cpp' CMakeLists.txt` will help you locate the filenames in `CMakeLists.txt`. But things will get [messy](https://pastebin.com/FEst4MFR) on a non-trivial project. It may be easier to let the compiler tell you of the problems with the failed compile.

Comment: My opinion, you should modify the CMake files to match the case of the files *exactly*. With that number of files to check, you can simply navigate to the directories containing the files, run `ls -1` to obtain a list, then copy/paste that list into CMake; hopefully, that would not be too time-consuming!

Comment: "I had gotten an error saying fatal error: stdafx.h: No such file or directory" - At **which stage** you have got such error? At `cmake` running, when CMake processes `CMakeLists.txt`? Or when the compiler (which one?) compiles the project's files. This aspect is extremely **important** for understand your issue. Please, show **exact error message**. See that [meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146/why-should-i-post-complete-errors-why-isnt-the-message-itself-enough) about why not-complete error messages are not so useful.

Comment: @Tsyvarev the error occurs when the cxx compiler tries to build StdAfx.cpp.

Comment: @Tsyvarev error message added.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1951951/when-including-header-files-is-the-path-case-sensitive

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is not with cmake, but with the filesystem. The filesystems in linux are generally case sensitive. stdafx.h is not the same file as Stdafx.h. If your CMakeLists.txt and source files use wrong case that doesn't match the name of the file, then the project is not compatible with linux and its filesystems. So, your options are:

1. Use a case-insensitive filesystem, since that is what the project supports

   1. You could try a case-insensitive filesystem on linux, but that is a hacky solution.
   2. Use windows.
2. Fix the project to support case sensitive filesystems by correcting the filenames and their references in CMakeLists.txt and inclusions. Note that there may be further problems when executing the program if it has been written with expectation of case-insensitive filesystem.

> I'm never gonna finish anything

Simple solution: Change all filenames to lower case, change all references in CMakeLists.txt and inclusions in source to lower case: No need to perform a comparison or try to figure out include roots. Both can be performed with a short shell script. Although technically not correct because the source files have non-regular grammar, regular expression is probably enough to match include directives.

Comment: Im gonna mark this as the answer, as it looks like for my specific case, using a script is the only way to change all the filenames to the correct format.

Comment: You have to change the case in the `#include`, too.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use `file` method for collecting all the files you need to build, for example:

```
file(GLOB SRCS "*.cpp")
file(GLOB HDRS "*.h")

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${HDRS} ${SRCS})
```

**UPD:**
By so you can only collect any files no matter what their names are. You'd better to change filenames through some script.

Comment: You should probably use `CONFIGURE_DEPENDS` with globbed sources.

Comment: I've seen people recommend against globbing files, as I'm not sure how the files will change. Some modules of the project only require 10-15 .cpp files. How would I use glob to only grab those instead of every single .cpp file.

Comment: or in your example
    `file(GLOB Sources "*.cpp")
    file(GLOB Headers "*.h")

    add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${HDRS} ${SRCS})`

Comment: @YevheniiMamontov Glob would only add case mismatched .h and .cpp files, what about a `#include stdafx.h`, where a file called `StdAfx.h` would be added because of the glob, yet the include is still looking for the lowercase version. I would still be unable to find the lowercase `stdafx.h` file regardless of glob or no glob.

Comment: @Bendrix, you are completely right.
By so, you only can collect files no matter what their names are.
It's better to use some script that change letters to lower/upper case.

Comment: @Bendrix `Some modules of the project only require 10-15 .cpp files. How would I use glob to only grab those` modules should be separated into subdirectories with separate CMakeLists.txt for each, added with `add_subdirectory` in the top level CMakeLists.txt. In this structure, there should be no need for anything more complicated than glob that matches all.

Answer (score 0):

Changing capitalization manually for the entire project might not be hard if you're using an editor that allows you to find and replace for the entire project.

There are examples like [Visual Studio 2017](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/finding-and-replacing-text?view=vs-2019#find-in-files-and-replace-in-files) and [Atom](https://flight-manual.atom.io/using-atom/sections/find-and-replace/).

Just try to press ctrl + shift + H.

Comment: I'm sitting in linux just using gedit to edit files. All the source files are on my linux machine. Ill take a look though, thank you.