# C2504: 'IFileDialogEvents' : base class undefined - why am I getting this?

Tags: c++, winapi, header

This is completely baffling me! I'm trying to make a custom `CFileDialog`, starting by copying code I used elsewhere - which works. But I cannot get this to compile and I can't see how it can go wrong!

I have:

```
#include "MyStdAfx.h"

#include <ShObjIdl.h>

class COpenImageFileDialog;

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// COIFEventHandler

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
class COIFEventHandler : public IFileDialogEvents, public IFileDialogControlEvents
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
{
public:
    // IUnknown methods
    IFACEMETHODIMP QueryInterface(REFIID riid, void** ppv)
    {
        static const QITAB qit[] =
        {
            QITABENT(COIFEventHandler, IFileDialogEvents),
            QITABENT(COIFEventHandler, IFileDialogControlEvents),
            { 0 },
            #pragma warning(suppress:4838)
        };
        return QISearch(this, qit, riid, ppv);
    }

    IFACEMETHODIMP_(ULONG) AddRef()
    {
        return InterlockedIncrement(&_cRef);
    }

    IFACEMETHODIMP_(ULONG) Release()
    {
        long cRef = InterlockedDecrement(&_cRef);
        if (!cRef)
        {
            delete this;
        }
        return cRef;
    }

    // IFileDialogEvents methods
    IFACEMETHODIMP OnFileOk(IFileDialog* pfd) { return S_OK; };
    IFACEMETHODIMP OnFolderChange(IFileDialog* pfd) { return S_OK; };
    IFACEMETHODIMP OnFolderChanging(IFileDialog* pfd, IShellItem* psi);
    IFACEMETHODIMP OnHelp(IFileDialog* pfd) { return S_OK; };
    IFACEMETHODIMP OnSelectionChange(IFileDialog* pfd);
    IFACEMETHODIMP OnShareViolation(IFileDialog* pfd, IShellItem* psi, FDE_SHAREVIOLATION_RESPONSE* psvr) { return S_OK; };
    IFACEMETHODIMP OnTypeChange(IFileDialog* pfd) { return S_OK; };
    IFACEMETHODIMP OnOverwrite(IFileDialog* pfd, IShellItem* psi, FDE_OVERWRITE_RESPONSE* povr) { return S_OK; };

    // IFileDialogControlEvents methods
    IFACEMETHODIMP OnItemSelected(IFileDialogCustomize* pfdc, DWORD dwIDCtl, DWORD dwIDItem) { return S_OK; };
    IFACEMETHODIMP OnButtonClicked(IFileDialogCustomize* pfdc, DWORD dwIDCtl) { return S_OK; };
    IFACEMETHODIMP OnCheckButtonToggled(IFileDialogCustomize* pfdc, DWORD dwIDCtl, BOOL bVal) { return S_OK; };
    IFACEMETHODIMP OnControlActivating(IFileDialogCustomize* pfdc, DWORD dwIDCtl) { return S_OK; };

    COIFEventHandler() : _cRef(1) { };
    ~COIFEventHandler() { };
    COpenImageFileDialog* m_pParent;

private:
    long _cRef;

    BOOL PathFromShellItem(IShellItem* pItem, CString& sPath);
};
```

In the code I copied I don't have / didn't need the `ShObjIdl.h` include, but this version gave me `C2504: 'IFileDialogEvents' : base class undefined` so I added it directly. It still gives me `C2504`. What can be going wrong between the include statement and the class declaration??? Is there a way to 'debug' this?

Comment: ¿Which Windows version are you targeting? ¿Did you configure Windows SDK headers? ¿What are the values defined for `NTDDI_VERSION` and `WINVER`?

Comment: `NTDDI_VERSION` is 0x06000000 and `WINVER` is 0x0601 - but I think you may be on to something. If I just compile the source file, it works...but it fails when I try to build the app. I think a `#pragma once` might be messing me up...somewhere

Comment: According with [MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nn-shobjidl_core-ifiledialogevents) you must include `Shobjidl.h` not `ShObjIdl.h`

Comment: @Ripi2 File names are not case sensitive so this should not be an issue. And `ShObjIdl.h` is actually a correct file name, at least in recent SDKs.

Comment: @user7860670 Well, it depends on platform and compiler. See this https://stackoverflow.com/q/1951951/3871028